# exit a loop if a record is returned

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, loops

I have following loop in a stored procedure that is working as expected. It generates given number of sql queries. What I need to do is to exit the loop if one or more records are returned.

```
set hour_inc = 1 ;
days_loop: loop
    if  hour_inc > p_hours then         
        leave days_loop ;
    end if ;    

        set @sqlstr = some sql query ;   

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstr;
        EXECUTE stmt  ;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;  

    set hour_inc = hour_inc + 1 ;
end loop days_loop ;
```

Comment: can use **break** and **continue** statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

```
IF FOUND_ROWS() > 0 THEN
  LEAVE days_loop;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [leave](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/leave-statement.html) to break out of the loop

Comment: I imagine the question is more about determining the number of records returned by the prepared statement.

Comment: eggyal is correct. I need to leave the loop if more than 0 records returned.